# How do I earn the "I am a genius!" Achievement?

Tags: achievements, surgeon-simulator

I recently bought Surgeon Simulator from the App Store and there are a list of achievements you can earn. I was scrolling through the achievements and I happen to see an achievement where you have to create a hammerhead shark. I am confused, so how do I earn this achievement?

Comment: put the head of a hammer on a shark? lol

Comment: A true genius wouldn't have to ask would they? ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is quite simple actually. Take this achievement in literal terms and strike the patient in the head during an operation. I hope this helps!

Comment: That's how I lost my medical license.

Answer (score 2):

You need to hit the patient in the head with a hammer to get this achievement . You will actually need to perform this procedure during the eye transplant.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by gouging the eye halfway out in Eye surgery then striking the patient on the temple with your hand. I did this with all my fingers contracted. Might've been a glitch but it worked for me.

Comment: Are you certain you have to gouge out the eye? The other answers do not mention this.

Comment: This is just how I got it. I'm not sure if you have to gouge out the eye or not.